# User Profile Synchronization with Active Directory not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

In sharepoint 2010, user profile synchronization is not working.Currently,user profile are set to sync with active directory.Some user profile properties are set to import and some are set to export. When I run user profile synchronization service neither it updates the active directory nor active directory updates the user profile database.

I checked ULS log no error.
However, this screenshot may help to identify the problem but I don't see this as a problem unless someone recommends otherwise.
[image]
[image: notification]

updates:
When I run incremental / full synchronization two services, User Profile Service **and** User Profile Synchronization Service are not starting.

update2:UPS and UPSS is showing started & when check and run full sync it only shows user profile service application -user profile incremental synchronisation instead isntead of full.

Comment: Have you tried to restart UPS in *"services on this server"*

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP do I also need to start User Profile Synchronization Service as well? or just User Profile Service?

Answer (score 1):

User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service should be started prior to starting the sync. All UPS services must be running and also, on your server in services.msc you should check if both ForeFront services are running.

If your User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service are not running, that means that your ForeFront services are not running. This measn that your FIM is not working and sync is not possible.

Robi

Comment: started both User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service it sync is still not happening do i need to do something else like reset IIS do full sync or restart other services?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure User Profile Service  and User Profile Synchronization Service  are all started.

Make sure that the farm account is a member of the Administrators group on the server on which you are trying to start the User Profile Synchronization service, then restart the SharePoint Timer Service.

Make sure the Forefront Identity Manager Service and Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service were both started.

Verify Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service and the Forefront Identity Manager Service are running in the identity of the account which has Farm Administrator access rights.